# OpenCL: How can I pass parameter with size greater than max_parameter_size?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl

Out of curiosity to find maximum parameter size that I can pass when invoking the OpenCL kernel, I found that I can pass an array with size greater than the maximum size. Here's what is happening:
( by the by, I am using pyopencl )

```
>>> plat = cl.get_platforms()
>>> dev = plat[0].get_devices( cl.device_type.ALL )
>>> dev[0]
<pyopencl.Device 'Juniper' on 'AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing' at 0x58fde60>
>>> dev[0].max_parameter_size
1024
```

**On google search, I learned that 1024 is in Bytes.** ( I forgot where it was stated, I think an Nvidia forum. )

Now, I ran this script:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

plat = cl.get_platforms()
dev = plat[0].get_devices( cl.device_type.ALL )
ctx = ctx = cl.Context( [ dev[0] ] )
cq = cl.CommandQueue( ctx )

kernel = """
__kernel void test( __global int* A, __global int* B ){
const int id = get_global_id( 0 );
B[ id ] = A[ id ];
barrier( CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE );
}
"""

prg = cl.Program( ctx, kernel ).build()

A = np.ones( ( 2**18, ), dtype = np.int32 )
B = np.zeros_like( A )

A_buf = cl.Buffer( ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY|cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = A )   
B_buf = cl.Buffer( ctx, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, B.nbytes )
```

before calling the kernel, I did the following:

```
>>> A.nonzero()[0].shape
(262144,)
>>> B.nonzero()[0].shape
(0,)
```

Then I called the kernel and checked for non-zero elements in B:

```
>>> prg.test( cq, A.shape, A_buf, B_buf ).wait()
>>> cl.enqueue_copy( cq, B, B_buf )
>>> B.nonzero()[0].shape
(262144,)
```

So, clearly, I can send and read back array of size greater than `cl.max_parameter_size`. **How is this possible?** or **Where am I going wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE refers to the max size of a kernel parameter passed to **clSetKernelArg**. See CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE and CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE in [clGetDeviceInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html).

Comment: `dev[0].max_parameter_size` gives 1024, where dev[0] is GPU and `dev[2].max_parameter_size` gives 4096, where dev[2] is the CPU on my comp and they have 1GB and 4GB of RAM respectively. So I guess `dev[i].max_parameter_size` returns the memory size available to the compute device..... Hence my assumption the they are in Bytes is wrong, where they actually are in MB. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should give up on guessing and assuming but rather accept what the standard is saying. As given by the answer, `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` tells you how much you can allocate at once.

Comment: @matthias, You are absolutely right, I shouldn't have guessed. But I failed to find the units ( i.e. bits/Bytes/KB/MB ) of the values returned by making these queries to the OpenCL device and I have spent hours on Google for this. Now, I know what they are. Thanks for the help.